# making an image clickable in android 2

Tags: android

How do make an image clickable in android?
I don't want to use an imageButton as it puts the image over a button.
i tried using following codes, but on clicking nothing happens..
in xml:

```
<ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/arrow1" 
 android:src="@drawable/arrow" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_x="12dp" 
 android:layout_y="90dp" 
 android:clickable="true" 
 android:onClick="onClick">
</ImageView>
```

in .java:

```
 final ImageView diskView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow1);


 diskView4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
         //my codes
    }
 });
```

Comment: android:onClick="onClick" remove this line...

Comment: Change onClick name in layout xml file. like, android:onClick="imageClick" in java public void imageClick(View v) you can't use onClick() method name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to add extra attribute

```
<ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/arrow1" 
 android:src="@drawable/arrow" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_x="12dp" 
 android:layout_y="90dp" />
```

This will do and your code seems allright. Trace your click by

```
diskView4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
         System.out.println("image clicked...");//check logcat
    }
 });
```

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html open logcat tab and you able to see your system message.

Comment: search for windows, you can find it easily.

Comment: it shows image clicked.. why am i not able to see any change in the emulator.. on other hand, without using any clickable routines, i can see the animation..

Answer (score 2):

Set the Background of the imagebutton to transparent or even better to android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground. then you even have an onClick effect like the standard borderless button.

```
<ImageButton
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/yourimage "/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `android:onClick="doSomething"` XML tag is very easy.

In the Context where you have inflated the layout(usually an Activity) you must declare a function like that

`public void doSomething(View view)`

You can find this information in the Documentation here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

By this way you get a cleaner Activity if the Image onClick is not dynamic.

**EDIT**

Example, in the XML Layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:onClick="doSomething" />
```

In the Activity if you want to open a new Activity for example

```
class ImageActivity extend Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle params){ //... }

    public void doSomething(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class));
    }
 }
```

In the View element you get the clicked view, so you can identify which element has triggered the function.

```
public void doSomething(View view){
    if( view.getId() == R.id.image_id)
        startActivity(new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class));
    else
        Log.i("Image", "Try to open the Activity from another view different from ImageView")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If above solutions doesn't work for you then you can try this.

main.xml

```
<ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/img_call_icon"        
      android:layout_width="40px"
      android:layout_height="40px"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:onClick="onClickHandler"/>
```

And in MyActivity.java

```
public void onClickHandler (View v) 
    {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.img_call_icon:

        // put your onclick code here
    }
}
```

Thanks...